# Minecraft server error on startup technic launcher

Tags: java, server, minecraft

Trying to make a Tekkit Lite server for minecraft and Im having some coding issues .
When I make the server and run the bat file:

```
java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar TekkitLite.jar nogui
pause
```

then i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoader$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.<init>(FMLRelauncher.java:48)
    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.instance(FMLRelauncher.java:40)

    at cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.FMLRelauncher.handleServerRelaunch(FMLRelauncher.java:33
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.main(MinecraftServer.java:1376)
```

Ive installed latest JRE 8 and JDK 8 for minecraft java edition, but still to no avail.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. I would post it to SuperUser if I were you

Comment: StackOverflow is meant to help programmers with programming issues. Unfortunately, this isn't the place for you to get help

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47897645/hive-appclassloader-cannot-be-cast-to-urlclassloader-although-using-jdk8). You installed JRE/JDK8, are you sure you are not running on JRE/JDK9 anyway?

Comment: I don't really think Super User is a good place for this *either* but it's *definitely* off topic here.